# how to change li class bg color

Tags: php, css

how can i add a background to this li class ?
I want to add code to the color blue for example.
What do I need to add

And where I need to add?

tnx !

```
<li class="tribe-events-list-widget-events <?php tribe_events_event_classes() ?>">

    <?php do_action( 'tribe_events_list_widget_before_the_event_title' ); ?>
    <!-- Event Title -->
    <h2 class="entry-title summary">
        <a href="<?php echo tribe_get_event_link(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
    </h2>

    <?php do_action( 'tribe_events_list_widget_after_the_event_title' ); ?> 
    <!-- Event Time -->

    <?php do_action( 'tribe_events_list_widget_before_the_meta' ) ?>

    <div class="duration">
        <?php echo tribe_events_event_schedule_details(); ?>
    </div>

    <?php do_action( 'tribe_events_list_widget_after_the_meta' ) ?>
</li>
```

Comment: you want to change to background of the bullet point of your `li`?

Comment: Changing background colors is not directly possible with PHP. You need to use CSS. Do you have a CSS file?

Comment: no  , I want to add background color of the text

Comment: So what have you tried?! Did you search the whole internet for answers? @user1461642

Comment: This question has already been answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4983713/css-change-list-item-background-color-with-class) and also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342626/how-do-i-add-background-color-to-items-in-a-list)

Comment: yes there is no answer ...

Answer (score 2):

css:

```
li.tribe-events-list-widget-events {

background-color: blue;

}
```

Comment: Write into a new file call "xyz.css".
In your html file, insert the link tag inside the head: 
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="xyz.css">
</head>

Comment: I created a CSS file and put what you noted above.
I opened the php file with the code with which I opened the question of where I added above the <? Php
Top of the document <head> <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text / css" href = "xyz.css"> </ head>

Now what?

Comment: If you inserted correctly, you should see there's color change.

Comment: What could be the problem

I created a CSS file
I put
li.tribe-events-list-widget-events {

background-color: blue;

}


In the PHP file
I put
<head> <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text / css" href = "xyz.css"> </ head>
<? php

And that

Comment: <a href="<?php echo tribe_get_event_link(); ?>" class="xyz" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a>

Answer (score 0):

```
You are using this code have you checked your function return the class "<?php tribe_events_event_classes() ?>". If yes then try this code:-
```

">

```
<?php do_action( 'tribe_events_list_widget_before_the_event_title' ); ?>
<!-- Event Title -->
<h2 class="entry-title summary">
    <a href="<?php echo tribe_get_event_link(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
</h2>

<?php do_action( 'tribe_events_list_widget_after_the_event_title' ); ?> 
<!-- Event Time -->

<?php do_action( 'tribe_events_list_widget_before_the_meta' ) ?>

<div class="duration">
    <?php echo tribe_events_event_schedule_details(); ?>
</div>

<?php do_action( 'tribe_events_list_widget_after_the_meta' ) ?>
```

Comment: I have a PHP file
I want to add background color inside code.

Comment: <a href="<?php echo tribe_get_event_link(); ?>" class="xyz" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a>

how can i add a bgcolor to his code?

Comment: <a href="<?php echo tribe_get_event_link(); ?>" class="xyz" style="background-color: blue;" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a>

It is using inline css . just use same approach for your li tag